# Making span id substitute li class in javascript Modal Pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a portfolio webpage, whereupon clicking a project, a modal pops up, with a carousel-gallery inside.

In my `.html` page, the projects are classified like this

```html
<li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">
```

The javascript refers back to the class "Project", upon Modal pop-up. I know wished to change this, so that the modal pop-up will not be activated upon clicking the id "PopUp". When when I try to change this in the Javascript, it does not work any longer. And I do not know how to fix it at this point. I want to say, that I have tried to change id's, span's and classes and neither was worked.

```js
window.onload = function () {

  span = document.querySelectorAll("#PopUp");

  document.querySelectorAll("#PopUp").forEach(LIelm=>{
    LIelm.addEventListener('click', showHideModal)
  })
};

function showHideModal(e) {

  if (!e.target.parentNode.matches('#PopUp , .modal-content' )) return
  e.preventDefault();

  let currentParent = e.target.parentNode;

  if (currentParent.matches('#PopUp') ){
    document.getElementById( currentParent.dataset.modal ).style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    currentParent.parentNode.style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```html
        <li class="Project" data-modal="myModal_1">

                    <span id="myBtn_1">
                        Irma Type
                    </span>

                    <span id="year">
                        2019
                    </span>

                    <div class="Describtion">
                        <p style="display:none;">
                           Typedesign
                           <br>
                            <span id="PopUp">
                              Images
                            </id>
                        </p>

                        
                    </div>

                
                    <div id="myModal_1" class="modal">
                     <div class="modal-content">

                    <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                          
                          <!-- The slideshow -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="carousel-item active">    
                              <img src="Images/Lirma/type.jpg" alt="img" width="100%">
                            </div>


                          <!-- Left and right controls -->
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                          </a>
                          </div>

                         <p>Some text in the Modal...</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript probably is running against dom elements that are not created yet.

I would suggest jquery for this.
1. Load jquery js in the header of your html page.
2. Enter the below at the bottom of your html page.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function) {
      //stick you dom manipulation here.
    })
</script>
```

Jquery is robust and browser agnostic (except for older versions of browsers). If it cannot be done with jquery, it probably just can't be done at all.

Comment: Hey @Rich K Thank you! I have a couple of question regarding the snippers of code, that you posted: 1. What should I put where it says "//Stick you dom manipulation here"? 3. The javascript I posted above opens a modal, but I also have another javascript file, that gloses the modal - should that be converted to jQuery as well?

Comment: DOM= Document Object Model (which is ~ rendered html object in browser). jquery should be everywhere you need it to be. Most folks use some sort of master page technology. So they only have to include it once.

Comment: Your js code above in your question is DOM manipulation code.

Comment: Hey @Rich K. I have tried doing everything you recommended now, but unfortunatly I have not been able to make it work :s